# Opening my third eye experience

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-effects

I've been meditating for me get a week and have always felt connected to my spiritual side. My dad has been meditating for about 30 years so I go by his guilds. 
I just wanted to know if anyone else felt what I have been feeing. 
After a few try's I saw an eye approach me and it kind of scared me away so I stopped the meditation till the next day. 
After that I've been getting vibrations coming through my body (from my feet to shoulders) every time I meditate. 
What should I expect next? Are there levels of meditation?

Comment: Hi Nicole and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource section](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might like.

Comment: Hi Nicole! Welcome! Could you describe for us what kind of meditation you were practicing when this happened?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, initially you may experience all kinds of glitches. When you don't meditate a lot of energy is stuck at different layers of your body-mind, and when you start meditating those layers start connecting to each other and energy starts flowing up and down.

So you may get a headache or feel like you are flying or see some flashes of colors, or get various body experiences etc. These are all like hallucinations, don't take them too serious. It is only a side effect of your energy moving to a more balanced state.

Some of them are very cool. Some of them can be super interesting thoughts or intellectual realizations. You job is to not fall in love with them on one hand, and don't fight them on the other hand, but let them come up and pass away so you can keep going.

Next you may expect funny dreams. Maybe lucid dreams when you know you're dreaming. Maybe flying dreams. Maybe dreams in which you go through walls. You may also start noticing how in your post meditation you become more steady and your senses get a lot brighter, like you feel more awaken.

On the other hand, at some point you may feel like meditation gets very frustrating. For some reason you start hating it. Usually that means you got stuck on some preconceived notion of how meditation is supposed to go. If that happens, let go of that!

Comment: +1 to what Andrei says. Right after an unusual event it's common to panic or obsess about it, but the memory of even the most earth shattering experience will turn mundane in six months to a year. So it's great you had an experience, but let it go, it's in the past. Inhabit the present.

Comment: The lesson I was always taught was to observe their existence, and allow them to pass by.  If the elicit a fear response, then such an ideal is hard to accomplish.  In that case, also observe the fear, and allow it to be.  Over time, you will approach things from different angles, and one day you will be able to observe such things without fear, and then choose to let them pass by.